# What is subgroup lattice of GL$(n,\mathbb F_q)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lattice-orders

I am trying search for subgroup lattice diagrame for the general linear group GL$_n(\mathbb F_q)$ but could not find any thing in the net.

Can some one help me by providng some link on it ? thank you

Comment: I doubt anyone has made one for general $n$ and $q$.

Comment: Well it is easy to see that any symmetric group $S_n$ will be included in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ (for any $q$). I claim that drawing the lattice diagram for $S_6$ is very complicated (it is however possible to draw the lattice up to conjugation but it is long...). This means that drawing the lattice diagram for $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ with $n\geq 7$ is just hopeless.

Comment: In that case, whatever has been done so far, will it possible to study ? I mean may I know from where I can get them ?

Comment: What do you need the subgroup lattice for?

Comment: I am studying group theory. There I came to know about lattice diagrame. and so far I have studied some of the lattice diagrame and also I made myself some of them as routine work. The more I am getting, more I am becoming enthusiastic to learn more about the structure of groups. Only thing is, some of the groups are so complicated that I failed to create lattice. GL(n, Fq) is one of them. So I am requesting help from the others if anyone or anywhere it has been done or not. Just for learning curiosity, nothing else

Comment: I think you need to ask a more specific question. There is a lot information known about the maximal subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ but even there you cannot give a complete description without knowing all irreducible representations in characteristic $p$ of all finite quasisimple groups. In other words, your question is much too difficult and you should start with easier problems!

Comment: I don't think it is feasible to understand in human terms the lattice of all these subgroups... as it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gap.app on a Mac (see https://cocoagap.sourceforge.io/ ), or xgap on Linux/Unix (included with the standard gap package distribution, although may require some installing some libraries to build), you can interactively examine the subgroup lattice of any reasonable-sized finite group that you like.  E.g.

`gap> GraphicSubgroupLattice(GL(3,2));`

You are unlikely to succeed in viewing the full lattice of a moderate sized $GL_n$.  I would suggest looking at limited portions of the lattice, if you would like to gain some intuition.  For example, (following the previous GraphicSubgroupLattice command) typing `MaximalSubgroupClassReps(GL(3,2));` in GAP, and then doing "InsertVertices from GAP" in the menu of the subgroup lattice.  Obviously, replace the maximal subgroups with whatever portion of the lattice you would most like to examine.  Working interactively can make it easier to focus on a smallish portion of a large lattice.  Right-click on a subgroup to get more information about it.

Alternatively, you can get a picture in graphviz format of the subgroup lattice of any group with `DotFileLatticeSubgroups`, then use the graphviz program to actually view the diagram.  For $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, best done only with small $n,q$, and interactive work is not (directly?) possible.